# qmail couldn't find any host named

Tags: domain-name-system, ubuntu-18.04, resolv.conf, plesk, qmail

System:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (fresh install)
- qmail
- dovecot
- Plesk 17

Mail configuration was done with plesk.

It is not possible to send any mail to any reciepents on different domains.

Log contains:

```
qmail: 1553679224.737428 delivery 12: failure: Sorry,_I_couldn't_find_any_host_named_example.com._(#5.1.2)/
```

dig example.com or dig -t mx example.com resolves correct.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 is systemd-resolved installed by default as local dns resolver.

Most of the linux tools can use this dns without problems.

qmail seems to query the dns in a different way like dig or other linux tools.

I found the problem by use dnstracer.

Doing

```
dnstracer -c -q mx example.com
```

returns nothing, because 127.0.0.53 is used.

Systemd-resolved is not a full dns server!

Doing

```
dnstracer -c -q mx -s 1.1.1.1 example.com
```

returns correct answer, because 1.1.1.1 is used.

So I linked the /etc/resolv.conf from

```
/var/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

to

```
/var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

and all works fine now.

You can also disable systemd-resolved completely and use resolv.conf in the old way.